# Editable dropdown box in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, dropdown, asp.net-core-6.0

I have ASP.NET Core 6 project. I need an editable dropdown box in one of the views. I tried datalist & javascript autocomplete functionality but both of them not working.

My code in view is :

```
<input type="text" name="medCompany" id="medCompany" list="ddlmedCompany" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
<datalist id="ddlmedCompany" class="form-control form-control-lg" >
@foreach (var item in Model.lstmedCompany)
{
    <option>@item.Text</option>
}
</datalist>
```

But this gives look as below:

[image]

and dropdwon box is :

[image]

What I need is only dropdown box and not test box which is displayed below dropdown box. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `class="form-control form-control-lg"` from `datalist`

```
  <input type="text" name="medCompany" id="medCompany" list="ddlmedCompany"  class="form-control form-control-lg" />
 <datalist id="ddlmedCompany"  >
        @foreach (var item in Model.lstmedCompany)
         {
           <option>@item.Text</option>
          }
   </datalist>
```

Comment: Yes but I cannot add new item to it. I need to add new item if it'e not there in list.

Comment: @Dnyati Ok, have a look at my update.